# Android Studio - How to send whatsapp mesages using FCM

Tags: java, android-studio, firebase-cloud-messaging

I Have a Series of Code i am Using and it can already send whatsapp messages. However the next step for me is being able to **send whatsapp messages using FCM** (Firebase Cloud Messaging). Has anyone done this before??

Also this is all in Android Studio!

Answer (score 0):

I hope this tutorial might help you though this is in `Kotlin` i hope you can understand
https://youtu.be/HoFWPPv1ih8

Comment: Thanks for the Reply. I Already Know the Basics of Using and Sending FCM. However i am looking for using FCM and Whatsapp.